# What do I need to use Smart card for windows login (no domain, just regular single local machine)

Tags: windows, login, smartcard

I have a reader from ACS "ACR83" and a brand new card from the same place ACO3-32 as a development kit and I need to use both of them to login into my laptop locally

I am not a part of domain, I am using Windows xp SP3 
what should I do to enable smart card login
do I need third party software to do this without domain
or should it be a domain environment to be able to do such a thing
this is the first time dealing with smart card, so I hope some one will help me Doing this

Answer (score 4):

You have some utilities but not many which enables you to login with a smart card and without a domain.
For example http://sourceforge.net/projects/eidauthenticate/.
Unfortunately this project works only on vista & later.

Else you should configure a domain, ask for a certificate & save it to your smart card.

Comment: @oliver it seems firstly need to load certificate into a smart card and then configure smart card with login account. could you tell how certifcate can be created and loaded in smart card?? Is any specific type of smart card needed here.